# Question about modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $B=A/\operatorname{rad} A$, where $\operatorname{rad}A$ is the radical of $A$ (intersection of all maximal right ideals of $A$). Let $I$ be an ideal of $B$ and $S$ be a nonzero right ideal of $B$ contained in $I$ that is of minimal dimension. We can show that there is a primitive idempotent of $B$ such that $S=eB$ and $B=eB\oplus (1-e)B$. It is said that $I=S\oplus (1-e)I$:

> [image]

(page 21, line 2 of [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)). It is clear that $S\oplus (1-e)I \subseteq I$. How to show that $I \subseteq S\oplus (1-e)I$ and the intersection of $S$ and $(1-e)I$ is $0$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $I\subseteq S\oplus (1-e)I$: Let $x\in I$. Then $x=ex+(1-e)x\in S\oplus (1-e)I$.
2. $S\cap (1-e)I=0$ Let $x\in S\cap (1-e)I$. Then $x=ex=e(1-e)x=0$.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. But it seems that $x=ex=e(1-e)y=0$, where $y\in I$ satisfies $x=(1-e)y$.

Comment: Since $(1-e)^2=(1-e)$ we have that if $x=(1-e)y$ then $(1-e)x=(1-e)y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

By $0\neq xS=xeS$, we have $eS \neq0$ and $S=eS$...Then $S=eS=eI=eB$.
It is easy to see that $I=eI\oplus(1-e)I=S\oplus(1-e)I$.